# Closing connection to Access DB with OleDb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have an Access Database I'm connecting to with OleDb.  Everything is working fine with connection and useage, but I need to make a backup of the file.

I am closing the connection:

```
  public class myDbHandlerClass
  {

    private OleDbConnection myConnection;
    //in reality this string gets built by properties to the class
    //it ends up being this...
    //Yes Jet 4.0 this is an Access 2003 database
    private string myConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=myDatabase.mdb";

    public void OpenDatabase()
    {
      //to open the database
      try
      {
        // Does a previous connection exist?
        if ((myConnection != null) && myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) return;

        //No database connection string is specified, can't continue
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myConnectionString)) return;

        myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ExTrace.WriteLineIf(TraceLog.TraceError, ExTrace.ShowException(ex));
      }
    }

    public void CloseDatabase()
    {
      try
      {
        if ((myConnection == null)) return;

        if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) myConnection.Dispose();
        myConnection = null;
        GC.Collect();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ExTrace.WriteLineIf(TraceLog.TraceError, ExTrace.ShowException(ex));
      }
    }
  }
```

No exception is thrown, connection state == closed, myConnection == null, but the .ldb file never goes away. My subsequent code which is supposed to move the "myDatabase.mdb" file to "myDatabase.bak" fails because the file is already in use - by my program.

How can I ensure it is actually closed and not locked.

EDIT:
I modified the code with suggestions from comments below and now it is working.

```
myConnection.Dispose();
```

And explicitly calling 
    GC.Collect()

is what got it working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Were are you declaring myConnection??

Comment: Chances are its closed but not disposed, it simply goes back into the connection pool.

Comment: I've edited the code to include the declaration and opening of the database.  myConnection is declared as a private variable in the class.  I've made sure that there is only one instance of the class, so there should only ever be one open connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `myConnection.Close();` try calling `myConnection.Dispose();`

As a matter of fact, I beleive `.Dispose()` is closing the connection as well, so simple replacing `.Close()` with `.Dispose()` should do the trick.

Comment: Actually, this is the problem. I added GC.Collect() after the dispose and now it works.

Comment: @trashrobber, you should set this as your answer and then when you can, accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this was the solution :

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Actually, this is the problem. I added GC.Collect() after the dispose and now it works.** –  trashrobber Aug 7 '13 at 21:14

I had the same issue and this was the solution.